# AWS step functions and optional parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, jsonpath, aws-step-functions

I would like to have a default value for a parameter passed into a step function

e.g.,

```
"Parameters": {
   "foo.$": "$.foo" OR "bar" if "$.foo" not specified
}
```

is there a way to do this natively with JSONPath or do I have to use a choice + pass state?

I'd even settle for using choice/pass if there were a way to not break when a parameter is not specified in the input.

If I don't include `"foo": ""` in the input, I will get an error like `"JSONPath ... could not be found in the input."`

Comment: Accepted answer became possible several months after I asked the original question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm solving this using a combination of the `Choice` and `Pass` states. Given that a state machine at least gets an empty input object, you can check if it has members present using the `IsPresent` comparison operator in the `Choice` state. If your variable of desire is not present, you can route to a `Pass` state to inject a default fallback object.

### Example Input

```
{
  "keyThatMightNotExist": {
    "options": {
      "foo": "bar",
      "baz": false
    },
    "id": 1234
  }
}
```

### State Machine Definition

```
{
  "Comment": "An example for how to deal with empty input and setting defaults.",
  "StartAt": "Choice State: looking for input",
  "States": {
    "Choice State: looking for input": {
      "Type": "Choice",
      "Choices": [
        {
```

Checking for existence and if so, also validate a child member:

```
          "And": [
            {
              "Variable": "$.keyThatMightNotExist",
              "IsPresent": true
            },
            {
              "Variable": "$.keyThatMightNotExist.id",
              "IsNull": false
            }
          ],
```

If the key variable is present and its child node `"id"` is `true`, skip the next state and hop over to the *"State that works with $.keyThatMightNotExist"*

```
          "Next": "State that works with $.keyThatMightNotExist"
        }
      ],
      "Default": "LoadDefaults"
    },
```

The following is where we inject our defaults:

```
    "LoadDefaults": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "id": 0,
        "text": "not applicable"
      },
      "ResultPath": "$.keyThatMightNotExist",
      "Next": "State that works with $.keyThatMightNotExist"
    },
```

At this point, there is an object to work with. Either from actual input, or by using the defaults:

```
    "State that works with $.keyThatMightNotExist": {
      "Type": "Succeed"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

For further information, refer to the [AWS Step Functions
Developer Guide, choice-state-example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html#choice-state-example)

Comment: Accepting this answer as the new "IsPresent" check is roughly what I was looking for, and did not exist yet when I asked the initial question.

Comment: @wrschneider nice. Looks like I got the need at the right time then

Answer (score 32):

There's actually a much simpler approach, it's still using extra steps; but it's better IMHO than a choice+pass. The concept is to define your defaults as a `Pass` state. This is required because we're going to merge the defaults with the input.

I've demonstrated that you can set more than just one default at once that reveals the benefits of not using Choice.

Note I *always* use `$$.Execution.Input` instead of relying on the input to the step function when I want to refer to the called args. This allows me to move steps around without fear of another state wiping them out.

```json
{
  "Define Defaults": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "Next": "Apply Defaults",
    "ResultPath": "$.inputDefaults",
    "Parameters": {
      "foo": "bar",
      "x": -1,
      "baz": null
    }
  },
  "Apply Defaults": {
    "Type": "Pass",
    "Next": "Start Work",
    "ResultPath": "$.withDefaults",
    "OutputPath": "$.withDefaults.args",
    "Parameters": {
      "args.$": "States.JsonMerge($.inputDefaults, $$.Execution.Input, false)"
    }
  }
}
```

This will then provide you with a yielded value:

```json
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "x": -1,
  "baz": null
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution using intrinsic functions that were recently introduced to SFn states language.

Comment: Thanks! I _thought_ there must be some way to merge objects like this, but couldn't find it in the docs. [Here it is](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-intrinsic-functions.html#asl-intrsc-func-json-manipulate).

Comment: This is a better solution than the accepted answer IMO.  It avoid clunky Choice steps and is also a good demonstrator of ResultPath, OutputPath and the use of JsonMerge and $$.Execution.Input.

Comment: This can be even simplified to one step: `"args.$": "States.JsonMerge(States.StringToJson('{\"foo\": \"bar\"}'), $$.Execution.Input, false)"`

Comment: @IvanTichy, I would debate that JSON embedded in a string is not simpler as it could be error prone. The explicit use of the `Pass` is easier to read/maintain and less likely to create errors with invalid or undesired JSON.

Comment: @BrettRyan What I like is that it uses only one step.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar issue that we resolved in a way that may be helpful dependant on what your SFN task will be doing. In our case it was a Lambda so we could handle the default behaviour within.

You can set a parameter to the "$" value that will take all the inputs provided to the SFN.

```
"Parameters": {
      "sfn_input.$": "$"
}
```

This "sfn_input" parameter will now be exposed to the stage and contain ALL inputs to the SFN. In our case, we could handle its optional presence in code.

This obviously only works if your task can eval the existence of the value.  There could even be a concept of an "initialise" Lambda added at the start of your SFN to specifically handle this and add default values that pass back out to the SFN.

Comment: Yes, this isn't exactly a solution, but it's a decent workaround.  I've done something similar in a few other places.

the key is, Lambda can check for existence of a key, and generate a default if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by creating a Pass State in the starting of step function with the combination of `"Result"` and `"ResultPath"`.

- `"Result"` of Pass State will be the value of `foo`
- `"ResultPath" : "$.foo"` in Pass State, so it's going to add foo variable in your pass input.

State Definition for the same will look something like this:

```
"Hello": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": "Added from Hello state",
      "ResultPath":"$.foo",
      "Next": "OtherStates"
    }
```

An example would be:
**Input to Hello state**:

```
{
 "bar" : "From input" 
}
```

**Output of Hello state**:

```
{
 "bar" : "From input",
 "foo" : "Added from Hello state"
}
```

In this case it's going to add value of `foo` as "Added from Hello state". So to avoid breaking things because of no `foo` present in input, you will have to define this Pass State as the very first state or atleast before the state where you are going to use it.

P.S. This is applicable for the case when you just have to add a single default variable as you mentioned. For adding multiple default variable, I would recommend to create a `Task State` and achieve creating default variable using a lambda function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the optional part of the question where u need to add the parameter only if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a cloudwatch rule that inserts json everytime the stepfunction runs.

If you go to Cloudwatch > Create Rule > Targets > Stepfunction > Configure Input > Constant (JSON text)

You can insert your default json there, that json is inserted everytime your stepfunction runs.

Comment: I don't think this is a scalable solution, although a nice workaround would not have considered using CloudWatch in this fashion

Answer (score 0):

JSONPath can only query your JSON, and you won't be able to add data on the fly, the default value would need to be present in your input. After many tests I was unable to find a "clean" way of doing this, but here's some methods to achieve this.

**Method 1:**

Since you mentioned you'll even settle for a way to not break if a parameter is not present in the input, this is actually quite easy to do, however it won't allow us to send a default value (except for an empty array) if the values are missing. To do this we can filter out specific values on our leaf nodes by specifying multiple children (['' (, '')]). For example the JSONPath "$.['Bar','Foo']" will filter out only the leaf nodes containing the nodes Bar and Foo, however it will not return an error if either or both are missing. In the case of all the children specified being missing it will return an empty array []. Here's an example State Machine to illustrate this.

```
{
  "StartAt": "ExampleLeafNodes",
  "States": {
    "ExampleLeafNodes": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "State1-BarPresent",
          "States": {
            "State1-BarPresent": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "Bar": "Baz"
              },
              "Next": "State2-BarPresent"
            },
            "State2-BarPresent": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "Foo.$": "$.['Bar','AnyOtherField']"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "State1-BarNotPresent",
          "States": {
            "State1-BarNotPresent": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "Field1": "Value1"
              },
              "Next": "State2-BarNotPresent"
            },
            "State2-BarNotPresent": {
              "Type": "Pass",
              "Parameters": {
                "Foo.$": "$.['Bar','AnyOtherField']"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Method 2:**

Depending on how much control you have over the structure of the input and if you don't need to reference any other variables from the input you might be able to do this in a single State using InputPath and Parameters. The idea behind this is to get your Input to the State in the form:

```
"OutputArray": [
  {
    "Bar": {
      "Value": [
        "Baz"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Foo": {
      "Value": [
        "DefaultValueFoo"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

The first element of the array should be the value which might be missing, if the value is missing the default value (foo) will be the first element. As the first element will always be present we can use the JSONPath "$['OutputArray'][0]..Value" to get the Value of the first element. After that in Parameters we can use the JSONPath "$[0][0]" to extract the exact value. Here's an example State Machine for this example:

```
{
  "StartAt": "State1",
  "States": {
    "State1": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Parameters": {
        "OutputArray": [
          {
            "Bar": {
              "Value": [
                "Baz"
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "Foo": {
              "Value": [
                "DefaultValueFoo"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "Next": "State2"
    },
    "State2": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "InputPath": "$['OutputArray'][0]..Value",
      "Parameters": {
        "Foo.$": "$[0][0]"
      },
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem when working with the CDK in Typescript.  As an additional problem, I wanted to include `null` as an input value so that the JSON path existed and could be passed to a Lambda.  If you try specifying `null` as a `parameter`, it drops the property (see endnote for workaround).

### Single Step Solution

A comment from [Ivan Tichy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056043/aws-step-functions-and-optional-parameters#comment136275851_74203476) led me to a single step solution that also handled nulls:

```js
const applyDefaults = new Pass(scope, 'Apply Defaults', {
    resultPath: '$.withDefaults',
    outputPath: '$.withDefaults.args',
    parameters: {
        args: JsonPath.jsonMerge(JsonPath.stringToJson(JSON.stringify({
            startDate: null,
            endDate: null,
        })), JsonPath.executionInput),
    }
})
```

There is a bit of a dance there, but it does at least mean that the value passed to stringify can be type safe (if defined prior to the call).

### A Reusable Component

I decided to extract this out into its own class:

```js
export interface ApplyDefaultsProps<T extends Jsonifiable> {
    defaults: T
    tempPath?: string
}
export class ApplyDefaults<T extends Jsonifiable> extends Pass {
    constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: ApplyDefaultsProps<T>) {
        const tempPath = props.tempPath ?? '$.withDefaults'
        super(scope, id, {
            resultPath: tempPath,
            outputPath: `${tempPath}.args`,
            parameters: {
                args: JsonPath.jsonMerge(JsonPath.stringToJson(JSON.stringify(props.defaults)), JsonPath.executionInput),
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Note that you can also supply a JSON Path to use for the merged result, in case this would otherwise conflict.

### Example usage

```js
interface Defaults {
    startDate: string | null
    endDate: string | null
}

const applyDefaults = new ApplyDefaults<Defaults>(scope, 'Apply Defaults', {
    defaults: {
        startDate: '1970-01-01',
        endDate: null,
    }
})
```

### Jsonifiable

You can replace `Jsonifiable`, its there just to ensure that the input will actually stringify, and I use the following definition:

```js
export type JsonifiablePrimitive = string | number | boolean | null
export type JsonifiableObject = { [property: string]: Jsonifiable } | { toString(): string }
export type JsonifiableArray = Jsonifiable[]
export type Jsonifiable = JsonifiablePrimitive | JsonifiableObject | JsonifiableArray
```

### Endnote

: if you use `JsonPath.stringToJson('')` in `parameters` you will get null instead of a zero length string.